# Databind the soure of ImageBrush inside ellipse inside a button

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to create a circle "play" button.
I want to use 2 photos. 1 is the default pic called:"PlayButton.png"
and another that should appear after the user clicked on the button called: "PlayButtonPressed.png" both inside Images folder.

I tried to use a simple databinding for the ImageSource of the ImageBrush to check this.
However the Inotifychange propery stays null. and no pictures is looked. not when the program run and not when clicking on the empty button.

how can I do that with data binding to controll the Image Source.

here is my code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="COMSimulator.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:COMSimulator"  
<Button x:Name="btnStart"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" 
    Height="50"  Click="btnStart_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding  Path=ImagePlayButton}"></ImageBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
</Window >
```

C#:

```
namespace COMSimulator
{


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public viewModeImage VMI { get; set; } 
    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent(); //init componenets 
        VMI = new viewModeImage();            
        DataContext = this;            
     VMI.ImagePlayButton = Consts.IMAGE_PLAY_BUTTON;
   }
}
}
```

C# viewModel:

```
namespace COMSimulator
{
public class viewModeImage:INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private string _imagePlayButton;

    /// <summary>
    /// this method init all window Items to relavent Data
    /// </summary>
    public string ImagePlayButton
    {
        get
        {
            return _imagePlayButton;
        }
        set
        {
            _imagePlayButton = value;
            OnProperyChanged("ImagePlayButton");
        }

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnProperyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

C# Const Value

```
public static class Consts
{

    public const string IMAGE_PLAY_BUTTON =@"Images\PlayButton.png";
    public const string IMAGE_PLAY_BUTTON_PRESSED = @"Images\PlayButtonPressed.png";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `DataContext` of the window to itself:

```
public MainWindow()
{            
    InitializeComponent(); //init componenets 
    ImagePlayButton= @"Images\PlayButton.png";
    DataContext = this;
}
```

The `Path` of a `Binding` refers to a property name of the `DataContext` of the element. This means that you need to set the `DataContext` to the class where the `ImagePlayButton` property is defined for your binding to work.

**Edit:** Since the `ImagePlayButton` property is defined in another class, you should set the `DataContext` to an instance of this one:

```
public MainWindow()
{            
    InitializeComponent(); //init componenets 
    VMI = new viewModeImage();
    VMI.ImagePlayButton = Consts.IMAGE_PLAY_BUTTON;                  
    this.btnStart.DataContext = VMI;
}
```

Comment: sill with the same issue :(

Comment: You don't see the Image at all?

Comment: Are you sure that there is an Image resource called Images\PlayButton.png? Please post your full XAML markup.

Comment: YES I am sure!!

Comment: It works fine for me so obviously you are doing something wrong. Again, post your full XAML markup.

Comment: @Barak Rosenfeld: Have you tried to put to XAML ImageSource="Images\PlayButton.png" and it works?

Comment: edit my question to add the model would appericiate if you show me in my code what to change

Comment: See my edit. You should set the DataContext to the object where the property is defined. Didn't you read my reply?

Comment: I also don't see where you actually set the value of the ImagePlayButton property to IMAGE_PLAY_BUTTON...?

Comment: edit it again for you too see  that it is in the Main constructor